# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Reports

Tags: workflow, reporting-services, reports

I created a workflow in **SharePoint 2013** and would like to start collecting information on how long it takes for each task to be completed. I know of ways to build this type of data into the workflow, but thought before I do that I should see if SharePoint already collects this data (why reinvent the wheel?). So I searched the web and came across promising results for SharePoint 2010 but couldn't find anything for SharePoint 2013. Here is what I found:

> Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 provides individual and aggregate
>   workflow reports to enable you to assess the efficiency of your
>   workflows and related business processes. You can use these reports to
>   locate problems with processes or to determine whether a group or
>   individual is meeting performance targets for a particular business
>   process.

Source:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713515%28v=office.14%29.aspx

This is exactly what I need, but how can I access these reports in SharePoint 2013? The link provided shows how to do it in 2010, but those instructions aren't matching up with 2013. **Does SharePoint 2013 provide workflow reports?**

Maybe that information is to be found under Workflow History, but as you can see my Workflow history has no data.

[image]

Comment: I believe there should be information in the "Workflow History" section when viewing the workflow status of an item, but it doesn't appear to be capturing any information.

Answer (score 1):

If you add Log Workflow History List and Set workflow status under Action , You will look at the detail of your workflow process.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken.

The history of the workflow (where your Red Arrow is pointing) will be what ever task you have logged.

For example:

In SharePoint Designer, on that specific workflow you are looking at, you need to create a log. To do this just type "log" after every task has completed, then name the task accordingly (Log "enter task name that was logged") and publish the Workflow. Once the workflow runs and it creates those tasks it should show up there.

Or

That might be where it shows previous versions of workflows that were used prior to the new workflow currently being used?

I hope i managed to help at least a bit!

Kind regards